# How to select particular region of image by mouse event in webview and show White Screen by Pressing Some Key

Tags: java, javafx

I have to select the particular section of image which is in WebView and crop the image and save the cropped image to another location and also save the main image also and I also want to rotate the image at a particular angle in the web view of image.

I have tried this code to give bellow.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MediaMonitoring extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

private static WebView mainWebView;
private static WebEngine webEngine;
private static WebView imageWebView;
private static WebView detailWebView;
private static Scene mainScene;
private static Scene scene;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    PlatformImpl.startup(() -> {
        mainWebView = new WebView();
        SplitPane mainSplitPane = new SplitPane();
        SplitPane imageSplitPane = new SplitPane();
        SplitPane detailSplitPane = new SplitPane();
        detailSplitPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        imageSplitPane.getItems().add(0, mainWebView);
        scene = new Scene(imageSplitPane);
        webEngine = mainWebView.getEngine();
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        imageWebView = new WebView();
        detailWebView = new WebView();
        mainScene = new Scene(mainSplitPane);
        imageWebView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (KeyEvent e) -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ADD || e.getCode() == KeyCode.EQUALS || e.getCode() == KeyCode.PLUS) {
                imageWebView.setZoom(imageWebView.getZoom() * 1.1);
            } else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.SUBTRACT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.MINUS) {
                imageWebView.setZoom(imageWebView.getZoom() / 1.1);
            }
        });

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        rectangle.setVisible(true);

        imageWebView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, (MouseEvent mouseEvent) -> {
                System.out.println(mouseEvent.getEventType() + "CLicking    >>>>>>>>>>>>");
                if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
                    rectangle.setVisible(true);
                    rectangle.setTranslateX(mouseEvent.getX());
                    rectangle.setTranslateY(mouseEvent.getY());
                }
                if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED && rectangle.isVisible()) {
                    rectangle.setWidth(mouseEvent.getX() - rectangle.getTranslateX());
                    rectangle.setHeight(mouseEvent.getY() - rectangle.getTranslateY());
                }

                if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED)
                    rectangle.setVisible(true);

            /*
             * Pane pane = new Pane(imageWebView, rectangle); final Scene scene1 = new
             * Scene(pane, 400, 300);
             * 
             * 
             * if (!imageSplitPane.getItems().isEmpty())
             * imageSplitPane.getItems().remove(0);
             * 
             * 
             * imageSplitPane.getItems().add(0,scene1.getFocusOwner());
             */
            //primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
            //primaryStage.show();

                //mainScene
                System.err.printf("X: %.2f, Y: %.2f, Width: %.2f, Height: %.2f%n", rectangle.getX(), rectangle.getY(),
                        rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
        });

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
                .addListener((ObservableValue<? extends State> observable, State oldValue, State newValue) -> {
                    primaryStage.setTitle(webEngine.getLocation());
                    if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED
                            && mainWebView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().getState() == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        storeDetail(webEngine);
                    }
                    if (newValue == Worker.State.SCHEDULED) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> showMainScreen(webEngine.getLocation(), imageSplitPane,
                                mainSplitPane, detailSplitPane, mainScene, primaryStage));
                    }
                });

        webEngine.load("http://pmmstest.ankiti.net/");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    });
    primaryStage.show();
}

static void showMainScreen(String location, SplitPane imageSplitPane, SplitPane mainSplitPane,
        SplitPane detailSplitPane, Scene mainScene, Stage primaryStage) {
    if (location.contains("img")) {
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().cancel();
        if (location.matches("(.*)img=(.*)")) {
            int n = location.indexOf("img=");
            int len = location.length();
            String imageUrl = "file:" + location.substring(n + 4, len).split("&")[0];
            imageWebView.getEngine().load(imageUrl);
            if (location.matches("(.*)target=wb2(.*)")) {
                int n1 = location.indexOf("target=wb2");
                String detailUrl = "" + location.substring(0, n1 + 10);
                detailWebView.getEngine().load(detailUrl);
            }
            if (!imageSplitPane.getItems().isEmpty())
                imageSplitPane.getItems().remove(0);
            if (mainSplitPane.getItems().size() >= 2)
                mainSplitPane.getItems().remove(0, 2);
            if (detailSplitPane.getItems().size() >= 2)
                detailSplitPane.getItems().remove(0, 2);
            imageSplitPane.getItems().add(0, imageWebView);
            imageWebView.setZoom(1.5);
            detailSplitPane.getItems().add(0, mainWebView);
            detailSplitPane.getItems().add(1, detailWebView);
            mainSplitPane.getItems().add(0, imageSplitPane);
            mainSplitPane.getItems().add(1, detailSplitPane);
            primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        }
    }
}

static void storeDetail(WebEngine webEngine) {
    if (webEngine.getLocation().contains("noob=1&noshell=1&ini=")) {
        int n4 = webEngine.getLocation().indexOf("ini=");
        int n5 = webEngine.getLocation().indexOf("&output_format=html");
        String find4 = webEngine.getLocation().substring(n4 + 4, n5);
        String html = (String) webEngine.executeScript("document.documentElement.innerText");

        try {
            System.out.write(html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SwingFXWebView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        String html1 = html.replace('|', '\n');
        String h1 = html1.replaceAll("\n", "\r\n");
        String path = "C:/temp";
        path = path + "/";
        File newFile = new File(path + find4 + ".ini");

        try {
            newFile.createNewFile();
            if (newFile.exists()) {
                newFile.delete();
            }
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newFile, true)) {
                writer.write(h1);
                writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SwingFXWebView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SwingFXWebView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        if (html.contains("date_data_path=")) {
            storeDateData(html);
        }
    }
}

static void storeDateData(String html) {
    int n6 = html.indexOf("date_data_path=");
    int len1 = html.length();
    String find2 = html.substring(n6 + 15, len1 - 1);
    String pathname = "C:";
    String cuts = "cuts";
    pathname += find2 + "/" + cuts;
    File directory = new File(pathname);
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
    String pathname1 = "C:";
    String db = "db";
    pathname1 += find2 + "/" + db;
    File directory1 = new File(pathname1);
    if (!directory1.exists()) {
        directory1.mkdirs();
    }
    String pathname2 = "C:";
    String ocr = "ocr";
    pathname2 += find2 + "/" + ocr;
    File directory2 = new File(pathname2);
    if (!directory2.exists()) {
        directory2.mkdirs();
    }
    String pathname3 = "C:";
    String output = "output";
    pathname3 += find2 + "/" + output;
    File directory3 = new File(pathname3);
    if (!directory3.exists()) {
        directory3.mkdirs();
    }
    String pathname4 = "C:";
    String scans = "scans";
    pathname4 += find2 + "/" + scans;
    File directory4 = new File(pathname4);
    if (!directory4.exists()) {
        directory4.mkdirs();
    }
}
}
```

By using this code I get the Cordinate of the Mouse, But I am unable to Draw arectancle on image.

Comment: If any Paid library present then recommend me